# Sequential Criterion Trouble

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 5x, \; x\in \mathbb{Q} \; \text{ and } x^2 + 6\; x\in n\mathbb{Q}$. Using the sequential Criterion, show that $f$ is discontinuous at $1$, but continuous at $2$.

---

I've show that $f$ is discontinuous at $1$, but i'm not really sure how to show that $f$ is continuous at $2$. I have $$|x_n - 2| < \epsilon$$ where $x_n \to x_0$. Since I do not have an actual sequence to work with, how can I continue with the convergence proof?  $$|5x_n - 10| < \epsilon, => |x_n - 2| < \epsilon / 5 $$ Then stuck

Comment: What is the notation $n \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o it means $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

To show that $f$ is continuous at 2 using the sequential criterion, you have to show that if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence with $x_n\to 2$ then $f(x_n)\to f(2)(=10)$.

Here's a hint: given such a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, every subsequence of it must also converge to 2. Consider the subsequence of all rational $x_n$ and the subsequence of all irrational $x_n$. What happens when you apply $f$ to each of these subsequences?

Comment: I don't understand how we are to show continuity for $x^2 - 6$.

Comment: Polynomial functions are continuous. This follows from the facts that the function $f(x)=x$ is continuous, the product of two continuous functions is itself continuous, and the sum of two continuous functions is itself continuous.

Comment: We can't just say that, otherwise I wouldn't have asked you how to show continuity. We have to show with definition of sequence convergence, which is what I am unsure on how to do

Comment: $f$ is not itself a polynomial function, so the fact that polynomial functions are continuous doesn't immediately tell you that $f$ is continuous. However, what I am suggesting is that this fact *together with* the sequential criterion is useful for proving that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't understand